# Hitting breakpoints using LLVM-vs2014 in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang, llvm-clang

I am using Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.3.5) and the official [LLVM 5.0.0 pre-built binary Clang for Windows](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html) (have tried 32-bit and 64-bit)

When I create a simple hello world project, compile using the LLVM-vs2014 platform toolset, and launch the Local Windows Debugger, I cannot hit a breakpoint. When I change the platform toolset to Visual Studio 2017 (v141), I can hit breakpoints.

Are there some extra steps required to get the Local Windows Debugger to work using the LLVM-vs2014 platform toolset?

Comment: Here on my VS2017 15.3.4 I have the only the _Visual Studio 2017 - Clang with Microsoft CodeGen (v141 clang c2)_ toolset (no _LLVM-vs2014 platform toolset_ whatsoever) and breakpoints work fine.

Comment: @Michael Walz, I want to leverage the code generation and optimizer from clang, not Microsoft. LLVM-vs2014  is a separate download from here: http://releases.llvm.org/download.html

Comment: You should mention this in the question.

Comment: @Michael Walz, I have made it clearer with a link.